# JSF cant resolve bean in xhtml file using spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

i have a simple JSF xhtml page contains xml:

```xml
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value='#{someBean == null ? "null" : "not null"}'/>
</h:body>
```

my `faces-config` contains:

```xml
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

and i have a java configuration bean like

```java
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean jsfServletRegistration (ServletContext servletContext) {
    servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());

    ServletRegistrationBean srb = new ServletRegistrationBean();
    srb.setServlet(new FacesServlet());
    srb.setUrlMappings(Collections.singletonList("*.xhtml"));
    srb.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return srb;
}
```

and a bean like:

```
@Component
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class SomeBean {
    public String message() {
        return "some";
    }
}
```

here, when i go to the page i get `null` string as response...

note: i can access my pages using browser.

why cant i get `someBean` inside xhtml file ?

Comment: Why not use JoinFaces which takes the magic out of using PrimeFaces with Spring Boot? http://joinfaces.org/

Comment: I guess you are missing @Named in the bean

Comment: I've answerd this question here, take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65246775/